# Routing between lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular

I'm working on an app that has two sections. A public and private (authenticated and unauthenticated) sections.

My main `app` routes are defined like so:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/public/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'public',
    loadChildren: 'app/public/public.module#PublicModule',
  }, {
    path: 'private',
    loadChildren: 'app/private/private.module#PrivateModule'
  }
];
```

Then in PublicModule I have:

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FullscreenComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'unlock',
                component: UnlockComponent
            }
        ]
}];
```

And kind of the same thing in my private module:

```
const privateRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PrivatePageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuard]
            }, {
                path: 'general',
                component: GeneralComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuard]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Where I'm stuck is on the default routing. When the user requests `/`, I would have expected this to redirect to `/public/login` but it does not. It stays at `/`. If I navigate directly to `/public/login` I see what I expect to see.

I'm not sure what I'm missing though.

A secondary issue I'm having is `/public` doesn't display the `/public/login` but that's not important yet.

Am I missing something about how routes work here?

And a third issue I have is when I try to access `/private/dashboard`, it redirects to `/`. I assume if I can get the `/` redirect to work, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for this ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Is there a Plunkr type thing where I can upload a zip of what I already have?

Comment: I'm not sure. Check out there if you find a way like that share it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `appRoutes` and `publicRoutes` to:

**AppRoutes**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'public',  //<--- Change this route path
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
        path: 'public',
        loadChildren: 'app/public/public.module#PublicModule',
    }, {
        path: 'private',
        loadChildren: 'app/private/private.module#PrivateModule'
    }
];
```

**PublicRoutes**

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FullscreenComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',              // <--- Add this empty path route
                redirectTo: 'login'
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'unlock',
                component: UnlockComponent
            }
        ]
}];
```

This should solve your first two of the three issues.

Comment: If I could upvote you 50 times, I would. So simple. If course. I just redirect from root, to public, to the component. I was trying to go too far, too fast. I use the same thing for the private path as well. Everything redirects properly now.

Comment: Glad to be of help to you!